# Is there a way to show that if the description of a language depends on some kind of global structure, then it isn't a CFL?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

So I've been reading Sipser's theory of computation book, and I've come across the pumping lemma for context-free languages, which as a reminder says that if a language is context-free, then there is some length p such that all strings longer than p can be represented in the form

$s = uv^i x y^i z$

and be pumped and remain in the language.

He then goes on to show that the languages $a^n b^n c^n$, as well as $a^i b^j c^k$ (for $i \leq j \leq k$) are both not context-free, using the pumping lemma.

While the proofs for both are just casework, to me the conceptual point here is that if your language relies on some kind of global structure in its description, then it's very unlikely to be context-free (since CFGs are just applying rules locally).

Is there some way to formalize this idea?

Comment: How does your view differentiate between $a^nb^n$ and $a^nb^nc^n$? Between $a^nb^nc^n$ and its complement?

Answer (score 1):

No, because the idea is wrong (or at very least, too vague and imprecise to be useful in its current form).  As Yuval Filmus hints, the language $\{a^n b^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ appears to have "global structure", yet is context-free.